# Run multiple Symfony console commands, from within a command

Tags: php, symfony-components, symfony-console

I have two commands defined in a Symfony console application, `clean-redis-keys` and `clean-temp-files`. I want to define a command `clean` that executes these two commands.

How should I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the documentation on [How to Call Other Commands](http://symfony.com/doc/current/console/calling_commands.html):

> Calling a command from another one is straightforward:
>
> ```php
> use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
> // ...
>
> protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
> {
>     $command = $this->getApplication()->find('demo:greet');
>
>     $arguments = array(
>         'command' => 'demo:greet',
>         'name'    => 'Fabien',
>         '--yell'  => true,
>     );
>
>     $greetInput = new ArrayInput($arguments);
>     $returnCode = $command->run($greetInput, $output);
>
>     // ...
> }
> ```
>
> First, you `find()` the command you want to execute by passing the command name. Then, you need to create a new `ArrayInput` with the arguments and options you want to pass to the command.
>
> Eventually, calling the `run()` method actually executes the command and returns the returned code from the command (return value from command's `execute()` method).

Comment: I read the docs, it doesn't show what to do with `$greetInput` or where run goes or how it works

Answer (score 1):

Get the application instance, find the commands and execute them:

```
protected function configure()
{
    $this->setName('clean');
}

protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
{
    $app = $this->getApplication();

    $cleanRedisKeysCmd = $app->find('clean-redis-keys');
    $cleanRedisKeysInput = new ArrayInput([]);

    $cleanTempFilesCmd = $app->find('clean-temp-files');
    $cleanTempFilesInput = new ArrayInput([]);

    // Note if "subcommand" returns an exit code, run() method will return it.
    $cleanRedisKeysCmd->run($cleanRedisKeysInput, $output);
    $cleanTempFilesCmd->run($cleanTempFilesInput, $output);
}
```

To avoid code duplication, you can create generic method to call a subcommand. Something like this:

```
private function executeSubCommand(string $name, array $parameters, OutputInterface $output)
{
    return $this->getApplication()
        ->find($name)
        ->run(new ArrayInput($parameters), $output);
}
```