# Is it possible to generate an entity and the corresponding table in a single command using symfony3 console

Tags: symfony, symfony-3.3, symfony-console

I am essentially looking to combine these two commands:

`php bin/console doctrine:generate:entity --entity="BundleName:EntitiyName" --fields="fieldName:fieldType"`

`php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`

I know I could write a script or simply chain the commands but I was wondering if Symfony provides an inbuilt solution.

I am using Symfony 3.3.

Comment: i don't think so

Comment: you can check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319602/run-multiple-symfony-console-commands-from-within-a-command.

Comment: @Albeis - that would do the trick but if that's the only way I'd be better off with a shell script so I don't have to redeploy that custom snippet each time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking into this some more this does not seem to be possible.

To work around this I created a batch script called `tentity` (table and entity), which I then added to my path:

```
@echo off
php .\bin\console doctrine:generate:entity %*
php .\bin\console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

Now I can simply do:

`tentity --entity="BundleName:EntitiyName" --fields="fieldName:fieldType"`